# Fetch version number after selecting file with FilePicker

Tags: google-apps-script

EDIT 06.01.2020 (below): UrlFetchApp code

Dear community,

I have the following situation where I am stuck:
I want to create a Google Apps Script, where the user selects a file in his Google Drive, which is then monitored and a notification is sent to the user in case the file is touched.

The background is that the user creates a file in my mobile app which is then uploaded to the user's Google Drive and which needs to be ensured to always be the same version.

I am currently doing this (for sake of quick testing) via a script running in Google Spreadsheets. The user selects the file and I output a few information like ID, name, etc.

However, I specifically need the `version number` which I can't get with my current setup and I just can't get it to work.
The handicap is, that I can not use restricted scope API, which can be found here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914 under `What are restricted API scopes?`

When I add the `Drive.Files.get(id).version` API call, the script doesn't show anything anymore and I don't know how to get this information with the current setup.

I am still a beginner in this area so I am probably missing something obvious or a simple solution.

I would greatly appreciate your insights and tips!

The code is the following, which is basically from Google's examples:
Code.gs

```
/**
 * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
 */
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**1
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request" 
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

dialog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaSyAk5AhAiDtqqXgUHd5kKUfVfhyXOgJikXQ';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        var output = doc[google.picker.Document.LAST_EDITED_UTC];
        //var version = Drive.Files.get(id).version;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id + '<br>output: ' + output;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following some recommendations I tried using the call UrlFetchApp. This call works, but it seems that the version number information is not present.

This is the code that I am using:
code.gs

```
function listSearchConsoleSites() {
  var url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/[file ID]';
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters"
  ]
}
```

When executing this code, I get quite a lot of info but not the version number. The data also doesn't change after opening/downloading the file so I can't get the information that the file was touched.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the drive v3 api [directly with urlfetch](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples/NoLibrary)(http get/post) without inbuilt advanced Google service?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you want the file on the drive be the same version as the one on your app, so the uploaded file always replaces the stored in drive file, is it correct?

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks I will try this way out.

Comment: @Kessy no the user creates the file on the app once and uploads it to his/her Google Drive. After that the file is not changed but sometimes fetched by the app to read its content.
I just want to make sure that the file is not touched by anything outside my app.

Comment: Can you specify the purpose or clarify the intention of this, because you can't forbid a user to modify his/her own file.

Comment: No, it's not that the user shouldn't be able to modify the file but I need to make sure that the file is not modified by somebody outside the app.
The file is part of a private key to sign Bitcoin transactions. If somebody unintentionally modifies it, it's not possible to sign transactions anymore so I need to monitor it for safety. Additionally the monitoring is done in case of theft of the private key part.

Comment: @TheMaster when I am calling urlfetch, I don't get any info about the version number. When doing urlfetch, opening the file and doing urlfetch again, I get the same response file.
Maybe I misunderstood something? Should I fetch the data and process it with another API?
Thank you for the support!

Comment: I haven't tried it. It was a  just a suggestion. Could you [edit] your question and document the latest urlfetch code and problem?

Comment: Since you are already using some Drive scopes, wouldn't it be better if you use Files: watch from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch.

You will need the drive.file scope that you are already using.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I updated the question with the code snippet using UrlFetchApp